# How to kill a process and release its resource in module?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, module, kill-process

I run a malloc bomb, which invoke `malloc()` continually. Then I write a module to find and kill the bomb, and my module found it and killed it by `force_sig(SIGKILL, task)`. 
The bomb was killed actually, but gnome-system-monitor shows that the memory held by bomb wasn't released :(

Could anybody tell me why, or how to kill a process totally in module?

[image]

Before detonate memory bomb.

[image]

After my module killed the bomb (by `force_sig()`), memory utilization was still high, very strange.

Comment: **gnome-system-monitor shows that the memory held by bomb wasn't released**  Is the killed process still showing up the gnome-system monitor? I mean how do you know that the memory being show belongs to the killed process?

Comment: I'm sure. I didn't open any other programs. The memory bomb obtain more than 2GB memory, but after bomb was killed, that memory were still occupied (showed by gnome-system-monitor).

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your gnome system mgr holding up memory somewhere and give its link here?

Comment: Ok...It look like memory leak.